# plusequal operator inside if statement

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
int toAdd = 0;
List<int> list = new List<int> {1500, 1500, 1200, 1200, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1000, 1000, 900, 900, 600, 600, 600, 600, 400, 400, 400, 400};

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) 
{
    if ((toAdd += list[i]) <= (3000 - list[i])) 
    {
```

This c# code works, this vb code doesn't:

```
Dim toAdd As Integer = 0
Dim list As New List(Of Integer)() From {1500, 1500, 1200, 1200, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1000, 1000, 900, 900, 600, 600, 600, 600, 400, 400, 400, 400}

For i As Integer = 0 To list.Count - 1
    If (toAdd += list(i)) <= (3000 - list(i)) Then
```

I've identified the problem being the '+=' operator, if i delete the '=' it magically works.

Does vb.net handle the '+=' differently than c#? I can't understand how am i supposed to do what i'm trying to do inside the if statement in vb.

Comment: When you say "it magically works" do you mean that it compiles?

Comment: In both cases you could do the increment before the if, which IMHO would be more readable anyway.

Comment: Not sure why the VB doesn't work, but I would avoid side effects in an if statement and make the code more explicit

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_operators.htm well according to this, it's the same..

Comment: I assume you're getting a compile error? I don't think you can use the result of an assignment statement like that in VB.

Comment: why don't you post the full code block for the C# and VB so that we can see what you are doing and or not doing..

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350433/vb-net-assign-value-to-variable-inside-an-if-condition) seems related.

Comment: @KyleW yes, it compiles, i wanted to make it a one-liner because the code is fairly short (5 lines) and there is no need to extend in this case, i can post the rest of the code but it wouldn't matter to the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should let you do what you need to do.

```
Dim toAdd As Integer = 0
Dim list As New List(Of Integer)() From {1500, 1500, 1200, 1200, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1000, 1000, 900, 900, 600, 600, 600, 600, 400, 400, 400, 400}

For i As Integer = 0 To list.Count - 1
    toAdd = toAdd + list(i)
    If toAdd <= (3000 - list(i)) Then
```

Comment: I'm not sure you're first example would work since VB.Net uses `=` for both assignment and comparison, vs C# that uses `==` for comparisons instead.

Comment: Your first example doesn't compile with option strict on, and if i turn it off the code doesn't do what i want, which i'm sure is because of the problem i faced.

Comment: Yes, you guys are correct.. I usually live in the c# world, I'll edit it.. thanks

Comment: @juharr is correct, VB uses `=` as a comparator as well as an assignment operator

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that in Visual Basic.

In C#, assignments are considered expressions. In VB they're statements, but not expressions. So this statement is valid in C#, but not VB (even when you remove the semicolon):

```
a = b += 12;  // works in C#, but not in VB
```

Or, said another way, assignment expressions in C# return a value. In VB, assignment statements do not return a value.

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation, i guess i moved from vb to c# too early to understand it.

Comment: `a = b += 12;  // works in C#, but not in VB` ***of course not*** you left the **";"** in which wont compile in vb... :)

Comment: Those #@$% semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think VB.Net supports what you're trying to do.  Consider `x = y = z`.  It won't evaluate that as `set y = z, then set x = y`, it will evaluate it as `set x equal to the result of whether y is equal to z`.  I think it expects the += to be an entire statement, and not part of a subexpression.  Its the presence inside the if that is screwing it up.  Thus, I think the best result is to remove that from the if statement.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To list.Count - 1
    toAdd = toAdd + list(i)
    If toAdd <= (3000 - list(i)) Then
```

Comment: in most other languages you can do `if((x = y + 1) <= z)` which is essentially what you are trying to say I think, but I'm not on the up and up with my VB code so you could very well be correct

Comment: Yea, i understand now, i will have to separate the += operator from the if statement, i've tried many things but vb doesn't allow it... thanks.

Comment: I don't know if "most other languages" support that. You probably mean "in C-derived languages." Which probably makes up the majority of languages in popular use today, but a small fraction of all the computer languages in existence.